# why i am getting "age" property in my object , it should be only in prototype

Tags: javascript, object, oop

why I am getting a age getter in [image]main Object it should be in prototype only

```
class PersonCl {
  constructor(fullName, birthYear) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }

  // Instance methods
  calcAge() {
    console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
  }

  greet() {
    console.log(`Hey ${this.fullName}`);
  }

  get age() {
    return 2037 - this.birthYear;
  }

  set fullName(name) {
    if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullName = name;
    else alert(`${name} is not a full name!`);
  }

  get fullName() {
    return this._fullName;
  }

  // Static method
  static hey() {
    console.log('Hey there ');
  }
}

class StudentCl extends PersonCl {
  constructor(fullName, birthYear, course) {
    // Always needs to happen first!
    super(fullName, birthYear);
    this.course = course;
  }
}

const martha = new StudentCl('Matha Jones', 2012, 'Computer Science');

console.log(martha);
```

maybe all the getter considered as a regular properties idk (pardon my English) is it becuase of super function or inheritance ?

Comment: "*considered as a regular properties*" - well only in the debugger, and even there they're not regular, as you can see from the color and weight of the font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `age` getter *is* on the prototype, not on the main object as an own-property like the console is making you think - that's why the `age` getter property in your screenshot isn't **bold** like the other properties such as `birthYear`, `course` and `_fullYear` which are all own-properties. Since Chrome 95, it will ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-95/#properties)):

> Always bold and sort own properties first in the Console

Note: The getter properties in your example also appear greyed out, which indicates that they're non-enumerable.

Here's another example that shows how a getter on the prototype still appears on the main object when logged, just non-bolded:

```js
const o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "b", { // add `b` with an enumerable getter (enmerable to remove the greyed out effect to highlight the change in boldness)
  get() {
    return 2;
  },
  enumerable: true
});

const r = Object.create(o); // creates empty object `r` with `o` as the prototype
r.a = 1; // own-property
console.log(r);
```

```html
See browser console for output
```

Example output in Chrome, notice how `b` is not bold, whereas `a` is as `a` is an own-property:

[image]

---

If you're unsure about if something is on the main object, the most reliable check is to use [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn), or if you can't support that [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)